# YII2 urlManager rule with unlimited GET parameters

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager

In YII2, how do we write a urlManager rule for any controller/action to accept any number of get parameters. I have tried //* but it didn't work. I am getting 404 page. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please, show you `urlManager` config

Comment: `'rules' => array(
                 '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
         )`

Comment: I have tried 

`'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*' => '<controller>/<action>'`

But didnt work

Comment: I don't understand your question, you can already handle this without any url rule... Show us an example of desired url.

Comment: For eg:  /user/register/param1/param2/param3/..../param-n

Answer (score 0):

It has come to my attention that currently one has to extend the class for UrlManager so it can accept such.